# Sum the 2 diagonals of a 2d matrix efficiently

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, diagonal

I've seen many algorithms that find the sum of the two diagonals of a 2d matrix using embedded loops but I've found myself this algorithm:

```
int arr[3][3]{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
};

// diags sum = 1 + 5 + 9 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 30
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    sum += arr[i][i] + arr[3 -1 - i][i];
std::cout << sum << '\n'; // 30
```

So is this a an efficient way? What do you recommend as a better method to do so? Thank you!

Comment: It is if you intended to count the middle element `5` twice. Related, but probably unhelpful: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236579/double-trace-of-a-square-matrix

Comment: @beaker: OK interesting. thank you.

Comment: On larger matrices where a single row fits on a cache line, but not the whole matrix, using `arr[i][N -1 - i];` instead of `arr[N -1 - i][i]` *could* be more efficient. But that doesn't really matter if you only care about 3x3 matrices.

Answer (score 2):

As always, the most efficient solution is to let the compiler do the work for you.

All calculations can be done at compile time. Nothing at all to do at run time.

The result is already available, before the program starts to run.

Please see the below example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

// Some typing saver
constexpr size_t SquareMatrixDimension = 3u;
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<int, SquareMatrixDimension>, SquareMatrixDimension>;

// constexpr function to get sum of diagonals
constexpr int getsumDiagonals(const Matrix& data) {
    int sum{};
    for (size_t i{}; i < SquareMatrixDimension; ++i)
        sum += data[i][i] + data[SquareMatrixDimension - 1 - i][i];
    return sum;
}

// OurTest Data
constexpr Matrix data{ {
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9}
} };
// Compile time calculation of sum of diagonals
constexpr int sumDiagonals = getsumDiagonals(data);


int main() {
    // Just show the result . ..
    std::cout << sumDiagonals << '\n';
}
```